# Data from multiple tables into datagridview C# winforms

Tags: sql, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, entity-framework-4

I'm developing an automation of manual system for a fuel pump. Up till now I've accomplished my tasks but now I'm stuck on something related to **retrieve data from multiple related tables** into one data grid view. I've already 'Google' my problem but failed to find the right way to move on. Here is my scenario Explanation:

- I've table named **'Department'** which have **'Vehicles'** table; **(1-*)** relation.
- then **'Vehicles'** table have **'Months'** table to keep monthly billing details; **(1-*)** relation.
- and **'Months'** table have tow tables **'Fuel_Bill'** and **'Lubi_Bill'** to keep the top level information of bills.(Both have **1-1** relation with **'Months'** table).

I've build this using entity-framework designer first model on SQL LocalDB.

So, now I'm stuck on showing:
-**Department's monthly abstract** view which have the details related to 'Vehicles' and the 'Fuel _bill" details of selected 'Month' in one data grid view.

It's a long question but to be clear I give these details, Please help me out, my whole project will fail if I can't accomplish this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I'm adding links to pictures of my data base structure.

Entity Framework model:

[image: Model]

And what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: View]

Comment: What is the actual question here? Can you provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to help us visualize your data, and can you show your desired results? I understand you basically want a query, but with what you have posted, there's nothing anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from `context.Months` to collect the required data for your grid:

```cs
var viewModels = context.Months
    .Where(m => m.Month_Name == selectedMonthName &&
        m.Vehical.Dept_Id == selectedDepartmentId)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Vehc_Number = m.Vehical.Vehc_Number,
        FB_Id = m.Fule_Bill.FB_Id,
        LB_GTAmount = m.Fule_Bill.LB_GTAmount,
        LB_GTQuantity = m.Fule_Bill.LB_GTQuantity
    })
    .ToList();
```

`viewModels` will be a list of anonymous objects with those four properties that you want to show in the grid. It should be possible to bind this list to the grid view.

Comment: Thanks Slauma from deep of my heart, I really appreciate and value your effort and time for me, I give you a 10+ vote (unfortunately Can't vote higher then 1). May I ask you for one thing more favor that if I want to show the details from Lubi_Bill table in the same gridview how should I suppose to do that? do I need to add another column which shows the details With Lubi_Bill Id? any idea on how to  do that please suggest me. Once thanks agian B-)

Comment: here is the link what I'm trying to do now thanks,  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhchZSm5cWnbkdOM1FtSXZFbHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CaptivativeMortal: You would add more properties into the `Select` block, like `LB_GTAmount2 = m.Lubricant_Bill.LB_GTAmount`, etc.

Comment: I've already tried that but this shows no records in datagridview :(